# How to perform a Join using Icriteria nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria

I am developing an application in MVC3 using nhibernate to fire queries on database.

I have Two Models.
HobbyMasters
HObbyDetail

HobbyMaster class Contains:

```
HobbyId
and other details
```

HobbyDetail Class Contains:

```
HobbyDetaild
HobbyMasters hobbymaster
other detals
```

Now i want to perform a jon between two tables using Icrteria:

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<HobbyDetail>()
                    .CreateAlias("HobbyMasters", "HobbyMasters")
                    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("HobbyMasters.HobbyId", "HobbyDetail.hobbymaster.HobbyId"));
```

Also this:

```
 HobbyDetail = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(HobbyDetail))
               .CreateAlias("HobbyMasters", "HobbyMasters", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
              .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("HobbyMasters.hobbymaster.HobbyId", "HobbyDetail.HobbyId"))
```

But i get an error saying **Couldnot Resolve Property HobbyMaster of HobbyDetail Class**

Please Help me

Comment: fyi, this question has nothing to do with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QueryOver, it's a wrapper on ICriteria with Lambda Expressions:

```
session.QueryOver<HobbyDetail>()
  .Fetch(hobbyDetail => hobbyDetail.HobbyMasters).Eager
  .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
  .List();
```

Comment: I am getting an error for HobbyDeatil saying cannot be declared n this scope bcz it wud give different meaning and Also gettn an error For Transformers.DistinctRootEntity